# How to auto-update middle table from an M: N model in SQL developer

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am doing the end-of-course work of BBDD and when doing the E / R model, I have a doubt, How do I update the record of a table M: N?. I have an M: N relation, A table for each entity and also a joint with their keys as primary in that table and foreign of the other tables. What I basically want to do is that when I add the record to the main table, it is updated in the middle. My teacher tells me that a possible solution would be a PL / SQL block, but the truth is that I do not have much idea how to do it.

Being a relation M: N I will create the table "teacher", table "course" and the table "prof-curs". How do I update in prof-curs when entering a new teacher or course record? Thank you.

Attached image of my E / R model made in a day.

[image]

Example of my SQL code

```
 create table profesor(Id_profesor int primary key identity(100,1), nombre     varchar(50), apellido varchar(50) not null,password varchar(50) not null,
sueldo numeric(10,2) not null,tipo varchar(50),Id_dept int not null )


Insert into profesor (nombre, apellido, password,sueldo,tipo,Id_dept) values ('ana', 'polo', 'ana','1500','admin',3)
Insert into profesor (nombre, apellido, password,sueldo,tipo,Id_dept) values ('pepe', 'garcia', 'pepe','1000','administrativo',2)
Insert into profesor (nombre, apellido, password,sueldo,tipo,Id_dept) values ('lucia', 'perez', 'lucia','1300','profesor',1)

create table curso (Id_curso int primary key identity (10,1),
                       nombreCurso varchar(50) not null, 
                        nivel varchar(4) not null)

insert into curso (nombreCurso,nivel) values ('ingles', 'A1')
insert into curso (nombreCurso,nivel) values ('ingles', 'A2')
insert into curso (nombreCurso,nivel) values ('ingles', 'b1')
insert into curso (nombreCurso,nivel) values ('frances', 'A1')
insert into curso (nombreCurso,nivel) values ('frances', 'A2')
insert into curso (nombreCurso,nivel) values ('frances', 'B1')
insert into curso (nombreCurso,nivel) values ('frances', 'A1')



create table prof_cur(Id_Profesor int not null ,Id_curso int not null,Id_idioma int not null)  

Alter table prof_cur
Add Constraint Fk_prof
Foreign Key(Id_Profesor) References empleado(Id_Profesor)  

Alter table prof_cur_idioma
Add Constraint Fk_cur
Foreign Key(Id_curso) References curso(Id_curso)
```

Comment: better if you could give some sample records of all 3 tables, and after update, records in all 3 tables.

Comment: You can make use of triggers for that

Comment: Thanks for answering.Could you tell me an example? Has never used triggers...

Comment: Triggers are used to perform any operation before/after performing inserting/updating/deleting data on a table. By trigger you can update/delete or do anything on any other tables too. There are various examples all over the internet on how to use it.

Comment: Do all teachers teach all courses​? Seems unlikely? So what do you need to automate?